# Reverse logic to logical path

Tags: python

**The original formula was: `c = m XOR (m << a) XOR (m << b)`

I just simplify it maybe it was wrong and now it can be reversible.

Let say:
a=1
b=2**

The simplified version:

I have the follow expression: `c = m XOR (m << a)`

Where =>

XOR is the XOR operator

m = 16-bits number

a = any integer number between 1-15

m << a => mean rotate m to left by a bits.

m >> a => mean rotate m to right by a bits.

Example:

```
c = m XOR (m << 1)
m =            0011000000111001
a = 1
m << 1 =       0110000001110010
m XOR (m << 1) = 0101000001001011
```

So c = 0101000001001011

My question is: what operations do I have to make from c to go back to m?

I tried:

```
c =              0101000001001011
c >> 1 =         1010100000100101
c XOR (c >> 1) = 1111100001101110
```

Obviously  1111100001101110 is not same with original m (0011000000111001).

And we can omit the 2 cases: all bits 0 (0000000000000000) & all bits 1 (1111111111111111)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid in the general case this is not possible. For example, consider the following two cases (all numbers in binary)

```
m₁ = 0000000000000000
a₁ = 1 (unimportant, any value of a works)

m₂ = 1111111111111111
a₂ = 1 (again, unimportant)
```

Both produce the same output (^ is xor):

```
c₁ = (0000000000000000 << 1) ^ 0000000000000000 =
   = 0000000000000000 ^ 0000000000000000 =
   = 0000000000000000

c₂ = (1111111111111111 << 1) ^ 1111111111111111 = 
   = 1111111111111111 ^ 1111111111111111 = 
   = 0000000000000000
```

Given `c = 0000000000000000` you can't distinguish the two cases and thus, without more information, your formula isn't invertible.

Comment: I have update the post with original formula. and let say we exclude that 2 cases, with all 0 and all 1 cases

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply! The two cases I mentioned aren't the only ones that collide, take for example (1010101010101010,2) and (1000100010001000,4), they both produce 0 as output. This works in general for any input where m is periodic and a is equal to the length of the period.